# How to configure "AuthType Kerberos" for Apache in macOS Mojave?

Tags: apache, kerberos, macos-mojave

I'm trying to configure Kerberos auth type for Apache but unable to find "mod_auth_kerb.so" module. I tried to build this apache module by following the below mentioned page but the instructions seems broken. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I'm using built in apache server with macOS Mojave.

Ref: http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/install.html

Thanks!